# How to display author titles that start with K

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xpath

I have a table that stores these documents. I want to show the author's titles whose name starts with K. My lecturer didn't pass this assignment for me, what's wrong?

```
SELECT XPATH('/bookstore/book[author = ".*\ K.*"]/title/text()',data) FROM bookstore;
```

```
<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume you didn't pass, because your query doesn't return anything. Your xpath expression returns an empty array. The main reason is, that xpath() doesn't support regular expressions (which is what you are trying to do as far as I can tell). To test for characters at the beginning you would need to use `starts-with()`

```
select xpath('/bookstore/book/author[starts-with(.,"K")]/../title/text()', data) as titles 
from bookstore b;
```

---

I would probably tackle this problem in a different way, in order view each matching title as a separate row, rather than in an array by using `xmltable()` to return one row for each book. Then match the names using `xpath_exists()`

```
select b.id, d.title, xpath('/book/author/text()', d.book) as authors
from bookstore b
  cross join xmltable('/bookstore/book' passing data
                      columns
                         title text path 'title', 
                         book xml path '.') as d
where xpath_exists('/book/author[starts-with(., "J")]', d.book)
```

`xmltable()` requires Postgres 10 or higher

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=705bed7deab8e83eb89ff67ace823096)